# I have created a database for the custom plugin but insert query not working

Tags: wordpress

I want to ask something related to my Edublogify Contact Form plugin. I want to save or store data and information in the database after submitting the submit button from the front end. I have created a database for the plugin but insert query is not working. I have tried lots of time but always failed.
 Please help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't  really  know  if  you  created your database  but  i will assume  yes , also  i could be  good if you pasted  your code for me to see.OK here is an  example  on how  to  insert  in a database.

```
 global $wpdb;

 $wpdb->insert( 
    table_name, 
    array( 
        'column1' => value ,
        'column2' => value 
        etc 
    );
```

That's  all  !  for  more  you can  read

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Hope  it  helps